# Spec - simple json api call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, rspec

I just want to test that a controller method is passing an int.

Test:

```
it 'responds successfully with mocked fto hours remaining' do
    get :fto_hours_remaining, {}, { "Accept" => "application/json" }

    json = JSON.parse(response.body)
    expect(json['hours_remaining']).to be_100
  end
```

Controller method (I tried the commented out block too):

```
def fto_hours_remaining
    @fto_hours_remaining = 100

    render json: @fto_hours_remaining
    # respond_to do |format|
    #   format.json { render :json => {:hours_remaining => @fto_hours_remaining} }
    # end
  end
```

I get the error:  `JSON::ParserError: 757: unexpected token at '100'` with the error pointing to `json = JSON.parse(response.body)`

Anybody see a mistake?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have right version in your controller:

```
def fto_hours_remaining
  @fto_hours_remaining = 100
  render :json => { :hours_remaining => @fto_hours_remaining }
end
```

Your action now render just string `100` this is invalid json.

Try in irb:

```
=> require 'json'
=> true
=> JSON.parse "100"
=> JSON::ParserError: 757: unexpected token at '100'
```

`render( json: { hours_remaining: @fto_hours_remaining } )` means render me in `json` format this hash `{ hours_remaining: @fto_hours_remaining }` that should be valid json:

```
{
  "hours_remaining": 100
}
```

And your test:

```
# return string "100"
number = json['hours_remaining'] 
# fails beacause "100" != 100
expect(json['hours_remaining']).to be_100 
# try this
expect(json['hours_remaining']).to eq("100")
```